# Where will I be able to get Font awesome image source and edit it if possible?

Tags: css, image, font-awesome

I'm using a custom template and don't know where the certain definition is.
It is a cart image and I want to replace the image with some other, so I need to find it. I only have found this bit:

```
.fa-shopping-cart:before{content:"\f07a"}
```

Comment: that is for font-awesome library, you can check i chrome webtools where the source is from. The image you see is a font.

Comment: Indeed, should have noticed that. In that case, this answer might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35507294/1582024

Comment: @user1582024 I've added the complete class .Moreover it's a font as said by Medda86

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Font Awesome is a web font containing all the icons from the `Twitter Bootstrap` framework, and now many more.

Whilst the implementation in `Bootstrap` is designed to be used with the `<i>` element (`Bootstrap v2`), you may find yourself wanting to use these icons on other elements. To do so, you'll need to use the following `CSS` on the desired element, and then substitute in the content value for the relevant icon
and was able to find substitute.It includes following icons such as:

- Web Application Icons
- Accessibility Icons
- Hand Icons
- Transportation Icons
- Text Editor Icons
- Brand Icons
  All these icons,and much more can be used just by using class.

Font Awesome does not use images for icons and an `img` element without a `src` attribute is invalid HTML.

What you can do is add logic to show or hide the dummy icon beside the image. Here is an example using a `class` on a parent wrapper:

```
<div className="show-icon">
    <i className="fa fa-..."></i>
    <img src="..." />
</div>
```

When the parent `div` element has a class of `.show-icon`, you can use CSS to show the icon and hide the image:

```css
div i.fa { display: none; }
div img { display: block; }

div.show-icon i.fa { display: inline-block; }
div.show-icon img { display: none; }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.fa-shopping-cart:before{content:"\f07a"
```

is a code part to say before the applying of your class you will have the icon identify by the code "\f07a".

You can find other one by following the link : https://astronautweb.co/snippet/font-awesome/

you can also set your on image by changing the code above yb something seems:

```
 content: url('yourimgpath');
```